# awk command to parse the output of df -h

Tags: awk

When I enter the command `df -h` I get the output showing the columns of filesystem, size, used, etc. What is the `awk` command to parse the output and display the following "Total Used Disk Space: 44G"

Note: 44G represent the value under the used column when you enter `df -h`

Comment: Are you trying to get the total used? Maybe something like `du -sh / 2>/dev/null` would be easier?

Comment: Note that the output from `df -h` may differ slightly between systems. You may want to let us know what Unix you are using and/or show an example of the `df -h` output on your system.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--total` flag to get what you seem to be after:

```
df -h --total
```

If you really want it exactly as you have stated then you can pipe it to `tail` and `awk` like this:

```
df -h --total | tail -1 | awk '{printf "Total Used Disk Space: %s\n",$3}'
```

This says:

1. Run `df` with human-readable output and a total line at the end
2. Send that output to the `tail` command which saves only the last `-N` lines, here we only want the last line.
3. Finally, send that to awk and print the line "Total Used Disk Space:" followed by the value in the 3rd column.

Comment: Perfect that worked, Thanks!

Comment: @user437534 Please accept and upvote the answer if it works. That's how we say thanks in Stack :)

Comment: You could also skip tail by using `df -h --total | awk 'END{printf "Total Used Disk Space: %s\n",$3}'`.

Comment: @Quasímodo the value of $3 or any other field or $0 is undefined in an END section. Some awks will retain it from the last record read, others will set it to null, others still can do whatever they like with it and still be POSIX compliant. To be portable you need `awk '{t=$3} END{printf "Total Used Disk Space: %s\n",t}'`